# Magento 2 code validation "Unescaped output detected." when calling Product Attributes in phtml

Tags: magento2.4, validation, pci

I've created Magento 2 modules, now when I trying to validate my code with Magento code validator and I`m getting ***'Unescaped output detected'*** in phtml templates where calling custom HTML attributes.

The problem is that I can't use escapeHtml method because my content is Html and shouldn't be converted to string.

I want to know how can I fix this issue

Answer (score 0):

use php echo short syntax with no escape.see below code:

```
  <div class="actions-toolbar">
        <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getActions($item) ?>
  </div>
```